# Proving that splitting fields of $x^n-a$ and $x^n-b$ are equal

Tags: solution-verification, galois-theory

We are assuming that $x^n-a$ and $x^n-b$ are irreducible over K where K is a field containing $n^{th}$ primitive root of unity $\omega$. We want to show that if $b=a^rc^n$ for $c\in K$, where $gcd(r,n)=1$ then the two polynomials have equal splitting fields.

My idea is the following:
We know that the splitting fields are $K(\omega,\alpha)$ and $K(\omega,\beta)$ where $\alpha^n=a$ and $\beta^n = b = a^rc^n$.
Then we have $K(\omega, (a^rc^n)^{1/n}) = K(\omega, a^{r/n})$ and now we use $gcd(r,n)=1$ and we get the final equality.

Is this okay or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes $c$ is in $K$, i'll add an edit

Comment: Conceptually, it looks like you have the idea, but your work needs to be more precise.  E.g. What does the fractional exponent in $(a^rc^n)^{1/n}$ even mean?... and "we use ... and we get the final inequality" definitely needs more explanation to tell what method you're imagining.

Answer (score 2):

The n-th root of $a$ is in the splitting filed of $x^n-a$. Thus $\sqrt[n]{b}=c(\sqrt[n]{a})^r$ in the splitting field of $x^n-a$ the desired follows.